# Java : replacing all URLs with anchor tags that aren't already in anchor tags

Tags: java, regex, url, replace

I'm trying to replace all non-anchor-tag-enclosed URLs within anchor-tag-enclosed URLs for a document. So given the string:

```
I have two urls for google: <a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a> and http://www.google.com/
```

I would like to replace it with this:

```
I have two urls for google: <a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a> and <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a>
```

Does anyone know a clean way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started (it works for the given example):

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String test = "I have two urls for google: <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">google</a> and http://www.google.com/";
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?<!\\<a\\ href=\")http:\\/\\/[^ ]*",
                                           "<a href=\"$0\"/>"));
    }
}
```

There are some problems with it:

- It doesn't account for whitespace in "a" tags, except for a single whitespace between the opening "a" and "href"
- It assumes a URL is "http://" followed by a zero or more characters not equal to space (" ")

This will work for simple examples, I'm not sure how you'd write a complete solution.

Comment: It is great answer. And it will be good if you add https to regexp too.
(?<!\\<a\\ href=\")(http|https):\\/\\/[^ ]*
And if someone want to add link beetwen acnhor element so you can change second part with 
<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>